# How to gobble a character, if present

Tags: macros, parsing

I would like to do the folloging:

Given a (complicated) string/macro `\String`, if it starts with * I just remove it, otherwise I do nothing.

So far I tryed

```
\def\gobbleast *{}%
```

then `\gobbleast \String` works fine if `\String` starts with an `*`, but gives errors otherwise.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I'm not sure I unterstand your question. But what I need is to erase * from \String, if \String starts with *. \String is something that will be expanded later, it may contains commands. Apparently the accepted answer works, I don't know wheter it works just because I tested it only in not-so-complicated cases, or if it does exactly what I need.

Comment: With `\def\String{{**}abc}` the first token of `\String`'s expansion is `{` and `\gobbleast` as provided in the accepted answer strips off the braces surroundinng `**` and removes the first `*`. `\gobbleast`  with `\let\ast=*\relax\def\String{\ast abc}` removes the token `\ast` because `\ifx` actually does not "look" at tokens but at their definitions/meanings. `\gobbleast` wiith `\def\String{{ab}c\relax def}` removes `\relax` and curly braces surrounding `ab`. With `\def\String{bla \fi}` you get all kinds of trouble. That's why info is needed what tokens the macro `\string` might expand to.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Ok I start to understand. Well I don't really know the "real" structure of `\String`. I use it in this situation: I have an itemized list and use `getitems` package to parse, which store the nth item in the magro \gathereditem{n}. Then I need to remove `*` from an item, and my idea is to use `\gobbleast\gathereditem{n}` or something like that. I don't know how many expansion I need.

Comment: @UlrichDiez bue I did not test with `getitems` yes, just testing in some simple case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case edge cases also need to be covered, where e.g. curly braces need to be considered, or where the string itself might contain imbalanced `\if...`/`\or`/`\else`/`\fi` I have a frightening answer where `\if..`-`\or`-`\else`-`\fi` constructs do not appear anywhere, but where branching is achieved using delimited arguments and tests for argument emptiness.  ;->

Since the whole thing is not very fast, it is intended more as something didactic to see how TeX proceeds in collecting tokens belonging to macro arguments, and how to manipulate the temporal order in which tokens are expanded by means of `\expandafter` and `\romannumeral` expansion and the like.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}

% ---- Layout ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%      The code for changing the layout is not of importance to you.
%      It is messy and only suits the need of having the result of compiling this
%      example fit on one page
\pagestyle{plain}
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pagewidth}{}{\pagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpagewidth}{}{\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pageheight}{}{\pageheight=\paperheight}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpageheight}{}{\pdfpageheight=\paperheight}%
\textwidth=\paperwidth
\advance\textwidth-3cm
\evensidemargin=\dimexpr-1in+1.5cm\relax
\oddsidemargin=\dimexpr-1in+1.5cm\relax
\marginparsep=2mm
\marginparwidth=\dimexpr1.5cm-2\marginparsep\relax
\textheight=\paperheight
\advance\textheight-3cm
\topmargin=\dimexpr-1in+1.5cm\relax
\headheight=0pt
\headsep=0pt
{\normalfont
 \setbox\csname @tempboxa\endcsname\hbox{0123456789}%
 \global\footskip=\dimexpr .75cm -.5\dp\csname @tempboxa\endcsname
                               +.5\ht\csname @tempboxa\endcsname\relax
}%
\parindent=0pt
\flushbottom
% ---- END OF LAYOUT ---------------------------------------------------------------


\makeatletter    
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@Exchange, \UD@stopromannumeral,
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherNull,  \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Check whether argument's leading tokens form a specific 
%% token-sequence that does not contain explicit character tokens of 
%% category 1 or 2 or 6:
%%=============================================================================
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{<argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                              {<a <token sequence> without explicit 
%%                                character tokens of category 1 or 2
%%                                or 6>}%
%%                              {<internal token-check-macro>}%
%%                              {<tokens to be delivered in case
%%                                <argument which is to be checked> has
%%                                <token sequence> as leading tokens>}%
%%                              {<tokens to be delivered in case 
%%                                <argument which is to be checked>
%%                                does not have <token sequence> as
%%                                leading tokens>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[3]{%
  \romannumeral\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
  {%
    % Let's nest things into \UD@firstoftwo{...}{} to make sure they are nested in braces
    % and thus do not disturb when the test is carried out within \halign/\valign:
    \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
      \romannumeral
      \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens#3{\relax}#1#2}{}}{}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@Exchange{\UD@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
  {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
  \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{<internal token-check-macro>}%
%%                              {<token-sequence-gobble-macro>}%
%%                              {<token sequence>}%
%% Defines <internal token-check-macro> to snap everything 
%% until reaching <token sequence>-sequence and spit that out
%% nested in braces.
%%
%% Defines <token-sequence-gobble-macro> to remove <token sequence> which in the
%% token-stream must definitely follow the token <token-sequence-gobble-macro>.
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner[3]{%
  \@ifdefinable#1{\long\def#1##1#3{{##1}}}%
  \@ifdefinable#2{\def#2#3{}}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Checking for a leading *:
%%=============================================================================
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@SnapToStar}{\UD@GobbleStar}{*}%
%
% Now you can check for a leading * via
%
% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{<argument to check>}{*}{\UD@SnapToStar}%
%                              {<tokens in case <argument to check> has a leading *>}%
%                              {<tokens in case <argument to check> does not have a leading *>}%
%
%%=============================================================================
%% Remove a leading * if present - due to \romannumeral-expansion the
%% result is delivered by triggering two expansion-steps:
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\RemoveLeadingStar[1]{%
  \romannumeral
  \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{*}{\UD@SnapToStar}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@GobbleStar}{\UD@stopromannumeral}#1%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Remove a leading * from the result of "hitting" the 1st token of the
%% argument with \expandafter once - due to \romannumeral-expansion the
%% result is delivered by triggering two expansion-steps::
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\ExpandAndRemoveLeadingStar[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
  \expandafter\RemoveLeadingStar\expandafter{#1}%
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatother

\begin{document}

% Testsuite:

\noindent Defining \verb|\test| from the result of \verb|\RemoveLeadingStar{No leading star}|:
\medskip

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \RemoveLeadingStar{No leading star}%
}%

\noindent
\texttt{\string\test=\meaning\test}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\noindent Defining \verb|\test| from the result of \verb|\RemoveLeadingStar{*Some leading star}|:
\medskip

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \RemoveLeadingStar{*Some leading star}%
}%

\noindent
\texttt{\string\test=\meaning\test}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\noindent Defining \verb|\test| from the result of \verb|\RemoveLeadingStar{{*}Some leading star in braces}|:
\medskip

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \RemoveLeadingStar{{*}Some leading star in braces}%
}%

\noindent
\texttt{\string\test=\meaning\test}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\noindent Defining \verb|\test| from the result of \verb|\RemoveLeadingStar{{*Some} leading star in braces}|:
\medskip

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \RemoveLeadingStar{{*Some} leading star in braces}%
}%

\noindent
\texttt{\string\test=\meaning\test}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\noindent Defining \verb|\test| from the result of \verb|\RemoveLeadingStar{*Some leading star and imbalanced \fi}|:
\medskip

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \RemoveLeadingStar{*Some leading star and imbalanced \fi}%
}%

\noindent
\texttt{\string\test=\meaning\test}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\noindent Defining \verb|\test| from the result of \verb|\RemoveLeadingStar{No leading star and imbalanced \fi}|:
\medskip

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \RemoveLeadingStar{No leading star and imbalanced \fi}%
}%

\noindent
\texttt{\string\test=\meaning\test}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\noindent {\bfseries\selectfont Defining \verb|\test| from the result of \verb|\ExpandAndRemoveLeadingStar\String|}
\medskip

\noindent... while \verb|\String| is defined to expand to \verb|No leading star|:%
\def\String{No leading star}
\medskip

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \ExpandAndRemoveLeadingStar\String
}%

\noindent
\texttt{\string\test=\meaning\test}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\noindent... while \verb|\String| is defined to expand to \verb|*Some leading star|:%
\def\String{*Some leading star}
\medskip

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \ExpandAndRemoveLeadingStar\String
}%

\noindent
\texttt{\string\test=\meaning\test}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\noindent... while \verb|\String| is defined to expand to \verb|{*}Some leading star in braces|:%
\def\String{{*}Some leading star in braces}
\medskip

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \ExpandAndRemoveLeadingStar\String
}%

\noindent
\texttt{\string\test=\meaning\test}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\noindent... while \verb|\String| is defined to expand to \verb|{*Some} leading star in braces|:%
\def\String{{*Some} leading star in braces}
\medskip

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \ExpandAndRemoveLeadingStar\String
}%

\noindent
\texttt{\string\test=\meaning\test}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\noindent... while \verb|\String| is defined to expand to \verb|*Some leading star and imbalanced \fi|:%
\def\String{*Some leading star and imbalanced \fi}
\medskip

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \ExpandAndRemoveLeadingStar\String
}%

\noindent
\texttt{\string\test=\meaning\test}

\medskip\hrule\medskip

\noindent... while \verb|\String| is defined to expand to \verb|No leading star and imbalanced \fi|:%
\def\String{No leading star and imbalanced \fi}
\medskip

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \ExpandAndRemoveLeadingStar\String
}%

\noindent
\texttt{\string\test=\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\gobbleast[1]{\expandafter\gobblehelp#1\relax}
\def\gobblehelp#1#2\relax{\ifx*#1\else#1\fi#2}
\begin{document}
\def\String{abc}
\gobbleast\String

\def\String{*ABC}
\gobbleast\String
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what `\ifx*#1\else#1\fi#2` does exactly?

Comment: @user126154 It compares the first token of the contents of `\String` to `*`, looking for an exact match.  If it finds a match it does nothing (which will discard the `*`).  If it doesn't find it, it outputs that first token which was not a `*`.  It finishes up by outputting the rest of `\String`.